# CANOpen network load higher than expected

Tags: embedded, can-bus, traffic, canopen

I am working on a project with a master computer connected via a CANOpen network to 4 slaves.

At each time step, the computer receives a measurement message from each slave, and sends them a control message. In total, 4 messages are received and 4 messages are sent at each time sample.

The message sent is a PDO with 6 data bytes (8 bytes including COB-ID)
The message received is a PDO with 8 data bytes (10 bytes including COB-ID)

My CAN network is configured at 1Mbit/s, and I run my program at 1000 Hz (1 ms sampling time). As the total load resulting from the messages described is 576 bits/cycle, the total load expected in the network is 576kbit/s, or **57%**.

What I see, however, is that:

1. The controlling computer measures a **load of ~86%** (with minima of 68% and peaks of 100%).
2. A USB CAN bus analyser I connect to the network registers a traffic
   of messages (count-wise) that is around *half* of what I nominally
   expect (i.e., 4 sent, 4 received each cycle, for 50 seconds should result in 50k messages, while I only see 18-25k). Moreover, I receive
   1-2 error messages per cycle from the slave devices that the
   network is overloaded. Before it is pointed out, even counting the
   size of these messages as part of traffic wouldn't get close to
   explain the anomaly in load.

What I'd like to know is whether my way of calculating the CANOpen network load is correct. For instance, are there any protocol-specific handshakes, CRCs, or any sort of extra bytes sent to make the network simply work? It's nothing I could see in the [wiki page of CANOpen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CANopen), but I do know there are such appendices to messages in the original [CAN bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus) standard.

Comment: It's not trivial to calculate CAN bus load accurately. [Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/422998/how-to-calculate-bus-load-of-can-bus/423413#423413) is one example of how to do it.

Comment: Also this isn't really a programming question, so it would have been more suitable for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Lundin I actually was about to ask it there, but found the CAN and network questions way more common and more clearly answered in here (see relevant tags compared on the two sites)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a CAN message, there is more than the data to be transmitted.
There is also the arbitration ID (11- or 29bits, depending on whether you use CAN 2.0A or 2.0B), there is a 15 bit CRC, an 7 bit EOF marker, the control field and also some other reserved bits.
Depending on the data, there may also be stuff bits.

Using CAN2.0B and assuming 48 bits (6 bytes) of data, you will get a message size of roughly 132 bits and roughly 151 bits for your 64 bits messages.

Summing this up, you will get roughly 1132 bits per cycle which is too much for a 1Mbit/s bus and 1000 Hz.

Hope that helps.

Comment: As far as I understand, in CANOpen there are 2 bytes of preamble with ID, function, and data size, but no CRC at the end (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CANopen#Communication). If however the 15+7 bytes of standard CAN are there also present in CANOpen, then you are right. That's what I'm struggling to understand

Comment: I think the CANopen wikipedie page does not show the whole picture. Take a look here: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#Base_frame_format). The CANopen frame is basically the green to red bits. But the remaining bits are still transmitted because of the CAN protocol used as transport.

Comment: Thanks. Not the answer I was hoping for, but it is what I feared. Do you have confirmation that CANOpen contains CRC? I just can't find it. If so, if you can update your answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: The Wikipedia page you have shared states (in top paragraph) that data link and physical layer of the CAN protocol is used. CRC is in part of the data Link Layer.

Comment: I initially could not find evidence that the CRC is part of the Link Layer. Most sources I find exclude the CRC from the depiction of a CANOpen message (https://www.csselectronics.com/screen/page/canopen-tutorial-simple-intro/language/en, https://www.ni.com/nl-nl/innovations/white-papers/13/the-basics-of-canopen.html). But while writing this message I found it. https://www.logic-control.com/datasheets/12/Manuals/CANopen/User%20Guide/CANopen%20User%20Guide.pdf at page 3 states there are 35 bits of extra stuff at the end

Comment: CANopen is on layer 7 (application layer). CAN is only Layer 1 and 2 (physical layer and data link layer). A CRC is (almost) always on layer 2 ruling out problems on the physical layer. Therefore you will not really find something about CRC in CANopen. But when you calculate the bus load (layer 1), you have to consider everything that layer 2 wants to transport over layer 1.

Comment: Even if I account for all the extra bits in the communication I still get a theoretical load that is 25% lower than what I measure. Does CAN itself use extra bits to setup communication and arbitrate multiple devices attempting to write on the same channel, or something like that?

Comment: Check the CAN standard. Especially the physical layer. One CAN message with 64 bits payload is at least 111 bits on the bus. Also there may be „stuff bits“. I.e. whenever there are 5 same bits adjacent, one different bit is injected. There are also some bus load calculators on the web you may use.

Comment: @raggot Forget about CANopen, this is done on the data link layers. All CAN frames have a 15 bit CRC. Though some CANopen frames like SDO include an additional checksum as part of the payload... but that's irrelevant for calculating bus load. You'll just confuse yourself if looking at high layer CANopen documents instead of CAN documents.

Comment: @Lundin thanks, assuming CAN and CANOpen were "swappable" has been precisely my mistake